# .NET Core template not available in Visual Studio 2019 - how do I add that?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxGaj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZHRn.png)

In my VS 2019, .NET Core templates all are missing. How do I add these to my Visual Studio? Please help me.

I have tried multiple ways to solve this, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you are looking for .NET 6.0 which **is not supported** in Visual Studio 2019, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1182)

There is a workaround [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/620284/how-to-target-net-6-0-with-visual-studio-2019), but as Microsoft suggests and avoid further headaches, try using Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: @marc_s  .NET 5.0 worked!                                                                                    [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0)                                                                               Once SDK 5.0 is installed , we need to add that in preview features . Then we will get the target pack for .net core.

Comment: @layanaantony: be **aware** that .NET 5.0 is **no longer officially supported** - no more fixes, no more security patches ....